# Ventana modal se cierra y no acepta validaciones

Tags: laravel, modal

gente les comento, tengo un proyecto donde estoy haciendo la vista para guardar un registro, esta vista es una ventana modal, ademas he creado un StoreUserRequest donde guardo las validaciones para ese formulario, dicho request la paso por el metodo store como todos saben, ahora cuando abro la ventana modal y para probar si el request esta funcionando correctamente , no lleno los inputs ni nada para que por lo menos me salga la validacion de required, le doy guardar y se cierra el modal como si hubiera guardado algo, cuando realmente no guardo nada, como podria hacer para que al darle guardar no se cierre la ventana modal sino que me pinte los mensajes de validacion del request, es decir que dicho modal no se cierre hasta que todas las validaciones del StoreUserRequest pasen satisfactoriamente?, adjunto imagenes para su ayuda amigos gracias  (obs: en la vista del modal no le he puesto el atributo required para que me deje probar las validaciones del FormRequest)uno
[image: uno]
[image: dos]
[image: tres]
[image: cuatro]
[image: cinco]
[image: seis]
[image: siete]

Comment: El código como texto por favor. No pongas imágenes de código.

Answer (score 1):

el detalle aquí es lo siguiente:

Estas usando **modal de Bootstrap** por lo que el submit en en tu modal **no hace un cambio por ajax**, sino que envía a otra url y por post, por ello hay cambio de pagina y por ende el "modal se cierra", por ese motivo es que visualmente vez que se cierra y vez el "no paso nada"

Para conseguir lo que necesitas es enviar por ajax usando javascript puro o apoyarte con jquery ya que estas usando la plantilla AdminLTE (viene integrado), y tambien no hacer uso de un submit, sino un boton normal (o un link con apariencia de boton) que llame a una función en js, que se encarga de enviar por ajax los parámetros y si está "ok" cierra el modal y si no pues muestra los errores mantiendo el modal visible.

> No soy muy bueno con el js, pero...

unos ejemplos podría ser:

El boton que hace el llamado a tu modal

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCreate">Crear</button>
```

De ahi el boto para ejecutar la función sería

```
<a onclick="grabarUsuario()" href="#">Grabar</a>
```

Luego en la parte del "Grabar llamaria a una funcion en JS, te aconsejo que le pongas un id a tu form por ejemplo '**formCreate**'

```
function grabarUsuario(){
   $.ajax({
       data: $("#formCreate").serialize(), // valores de los imputs
       url: 'url_destino', // aqui la ruta del post
       type: 'post' // método de envio
   }).done(function(){
       alert('registro creado correctamente'); // el alert solo un ejemplo
       $("#modalCreate").modal('hide');
   }).fail(function(error) {
       alert('Se produjo un error');
       // lógica para setear el texto y mostrarlo
   });
}
```

Espero poder haber ayudado en algo o darte ideas de como puedas dar con tu solución, Saludos.